# Fatal Exception: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR

Tags: android, firebase

**In Firebase console , I see that there are so many crashes on Firebase Messaging registration on complete.**

Fatal Exception: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR
aused by java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: FIS_AUTH_ERROR
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.blockingGetToken(FirebaseMessaging.java:626)
at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.lambda$getToken$4(FirebaseMessaging.java)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:2)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

**But i am not able to reproduce the same. But i see lots of crash in firebase dashboard for real users.**